# Does iPhone proximity sensor detects only faces or any solid object?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to turn off device screen when orientation is isFaceDown, the  way to turn off screen as google results suggest is by using following code

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].proximityMonitoringEnabled = YES;
```

or

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:0.0];
```

the last one doesn't serves my purpose as its still not completely turned off , where as proximity sensor doesnot seems to work always when I face down my device on my desk, so the question is does it sense proximity to every object, cause from my experience thats not always true or am i missing something here. Also could someone suggest a way to achieve turning off screen completely when orientation of the device is face down?

Answer (score -1):

As @Pétur stated in his answer, the proximity sensory was designed to detect skin in close proximity, but that isn't your biggest issue here.

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:0.0];
```

Is actually as close as you can get to turning the screen off. There is no public API that gives us this kind of power. The best you're going to get is to turn the brightness down to 0.0, hide the status bar, and create a all black view to present over top of the rest of your app.

Answer (score -2):

The proximity sensor is an infra-red sensor that detects heat radiation. You can use it to detect a face but not dead items unless they are hot.

Comment: so how do you propose to turn off display, if you may

Comment: As @0x7fffffff answers states.

Comment: The claim i put forth is a valid one. I would appriciate comments from those who express their disagreement by voting it down.

Comment: I don't think your claim is valid, at least not on an iPhone 4 or 5. I tried testing it against my desk(wood), cardboard, and a piece of metal that was about 60f, and all 3 triggered the sensor.